# Deleting the tcl/tzdata folder from the PyInstaller EXE file

Tags: pyinstaller

When I build an EXE file using PyInstaller it always includes a folder named `tcl`, which includes a folder with many files named: `tzdata`. (This is probably Python's `tzdata` library). How to make `tzdata` folder not be in the final EXE file?

I tried several options I found online but still no success.
Thanks

**updating:**
Meanwhile, the only option I found is to delete the `tzdata` folder from my computer before I use pyinstaller to create an EXE file.
The path is
`C:\Program Files\Python311\tcl\tcl8.6\tzdata`
Thus, pyinstaller cannot find this folder, and it cannot include it in the EXE file